# Loading kdb+ data into R

Tags: r, kdb

I'm trying to compile the l64_qserver from the [kdb Cookbook](https://github.com/KxSystems/cookbook/tree/master/r) but I'm missing a couple of files:

```
# make
/usr/local/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD gcc -g -O -fPIC -m64   -shared -D KXVER=3 -I. -I/usr/local/R/lib64/R/include base.c c.o -lpthread -L/usr
/local/R/lib64/R/lib -lR -o qserver.so
gcc: c.o: No such file or directory
base.c:11:15: error: k.h: No such file or directory
```

Where can I find these k.h and c.o files?
Also what does 'CMD' do after the R binary command in the Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files your missing are at the locations shown below

```
https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/c/k.h
https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/l64/c.o
```

Comment: After compiling it works great, I can capture the result of kdb queries in R objects. Thanks.